# Android installing an application programatically in the background

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-2.2-froyo

In my application, i am installing other apks on the start of the application to create a runtime environment. I have 3 more apks to install on the start of application and i want to do it at the runtime but i dont want any message of installation for apks. Installation should be done on the background automatically. thanks.

Comment: For every apk installation Android checks for the certificate before installation, so do not know if this can be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

follow the link - 
[Android install apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768930/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Comment: I want solution that do not ask for the installation, only install at the background without the installation message.

Comment: I dont think it is merely possible because android do ask for the confirmation. There may be variable result by the user.

Comment: you can go with services either. create a services and write the above code on onCreate method. check and let me know if it works.